# Rotator Cuff Muscles Categorization

Tags: muscle, back, workout-types, anatomy, deltoids

Is the rotator cuff considered part of the shoulder or back?

I heard on an Athlean X video I'll link below this one is a branch of the back muscles above and below the spine of the scapula, however it seems to me it is more of a shoulder based along with the deltoid.

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXvQe9payHw&t=508s).

Also which exercises would target these set of muscles.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotator cuff muscles are shoulder muscles, in terms of functionality. However in that video, Jeff was talking about muscle hypertrophy for appearance rather than function, and so included the external rotator cuff muscles, as those muscles are visible when viewed from the back.

The infraspinatus and teres minor perform external shoulder rotation, and are often worked using bands or cables, [rotating the arm externally with the elbow held at 90°](https://exrx.net/WeightExercises/Infraspinatus/CBStandingExternalRotation). The supraspinatus is much less visible, being buried under the upper traps, but can be worked using "full can" dumbbell raises, which are usually performed for rehabilitation rather than hypertrophy.